How to deal with loss of replicate?
I have run an experiment with two treatments (control/biocide),
one of which was quite stressfull for the crops I looked at and survival rate are really low for some crop cultivars (ie only one replicate remaining). Is there a way I can still run stats to test treatment effect on plant height or fruit biomass?

Can you elaborate on the sample size and number of cultivars in each of the two groups?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks Dimitri, as stated above sometimes only one replicate remaining at the end of the experiment on one side (biocide). three to seven on the other one (control) for some cultivars
